# column id does not exist Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

[image]
error at my Heroku page after deploying

I tried many things and search a lot on google, but those solutions don't work for me. Is there someone that can give me some tips on what I can do. Im really lost. Thanks in advance

https://buildblock-site.herokuapp.com

contacts/models.py

```
class CompanyInformation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    #
    #
```

setting.py

```
import django_on_heroku
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['buildblock-site.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']

#
#
#

django_on_heroku.settings(locals())
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.AutoField'


'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
```

Profile

```
web: gunicorn portfolio.wsgi
```

requirements.py

```
asgiref==3.3.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2
django-on-heroku==1.1.2
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
gunicorn==20.1.0
Pillow==8.2.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

I used:

```
git add .  
git add -A
git commit -m ".."
git push heroku master   
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations   
heroku run python manage.py migrate contacts  
heroku ps:scale web=1    
heroku local web
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I did to make it work for the people that looks for a solution. So this worked for me at least..**

create a **Procfile** at root dir

```
web: gunicorn Portfolio.wsgi --log-file=-

heroku login
heroku keys:add #get SSL key
```

Create a Heroku app (I did it on the website)
create a GitHub repo and push everything on it
then I go to Heroku deploy page, connect with my GitHub and push deploy my branch btn

it give me some errors so I did

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

Still error??? Then I add this in my **settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_on_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'portfolio-buildblock.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

# Static files
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portfolio/static')
]

# Media folder settings
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
django_on_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**my urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    #
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

later I saw there's no Static files??? so I did this

```
heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC
```

after this

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 
heroku config:set DJANGO_STATIC_HOST=https://d4663kmspf1sqa.cloudfront.net
```

don't ask me why... I don't know

and in the end I added database
**Settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "dynamo",
        "USER": "username",
        "PASSWORD": "pass",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

and it worked for me

If this isn't working... Delete the Heroku app and try again or check typos